# Que + pronombre interrogativo

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Yo he leído la siguiente frase: "Yo le pregunté que quién estaba con ella."

Pienso que es muy probable que la construcción gramatical de "que quién" sea correcta. Todavía no sé decir si es correcto o no. En el caso de ser una construcción correcta, ¿cual es la regla? ¿Cuándo lo puedo/debo utilizar?

Muchas gracias desde ya!

Comment: Nota: "que" es un pronombre relativo (o una conjunción en este caso), y "quién" es un pronombre interrogativo. He editado la pregunta para corregir esto, pero puedes revertir la edición o editar de nuevo si no estás de acuerdo. Aparte de esto, ¡bienvenido/a a Spanish Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La entrada para *[que](https://www.rae.es/dpd/que)* del DPD, en el punto 2.1.6, califica este uso de la conjunción *que* de "innecesario pero admisible":

> Delante de las oraciones interrogativas indirectas dependientes del verbo *preguntar*, es habitual en la lengua coloquial la presencia de un *que*, innecesario pero admisible, ante la conjunción *si* o el pronombre o adverbio interrogativo que introducen la subordinada: «*Nos pregunta que si nos gusta la exposición*»

Hay un caso en el que el uso de *que* es obligatorio, y es cuando se utiliza el verbo *decir* con el significado de *preguntar* y la oración subordinada comienza con un pronombre interrogativo. El ejemplo que da el DPD es:

> Un señor llamó diciendo (=preguntando) *que* qué pasaba con su ordenador.

En este caso, la conjunción *que* es obligatoria, porque sin ella la frase tendría un significado distinto (afirmación en lugar de interrogación):

> Un señor llamó diciendo (=comunicando) qué pasaba con su ordenador.

Aunque el DPD solo menciona los verbos *preguntar* y *decir*, estas consideraciones probablemente también son válidas para algunos verbos con significados similares, como "querer saber" (en lugar de "preguntar") o "gritar" (en lugar de "decir").

Comment: +1 Sólo agregaría que ese "que" en general se usa para repetir algo que la otra persona no oyó o no entendió. Y no limitaría su uso a los verbos "preguntar" y "decir", sino que lo haría extensivo a los verbos de decir en general.

Comment: @Gustavson curiosamente el DPD solo habla de los verbos "preguntar" y "decir". He agregado un párrafo al final de mi respuesta diciendo que esto es válido para algunos verbos con significado parecido, pero en realidad parece que no para todos. Por ejemplo, me sonaría raro decir "Inquirió que dónde estaba su chaqueta". Con "decir", muchos no valen porque tienen significados más "declarativos": "declarar", "afirmar", "manifestar", que no se pueden usar para hablar de preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Es incorrecto, se le llama "queísmo" dentro de las reglas gramaticales, (entre otros vicios del lenguaje se encuentra: dequeísmo, laísmo/leísmo/loísmo).
Éstas son variantes de las expresiones pleonásticas, como su nombre lo indica, el "pleonasmo" se trata del uso innecesario o excesivo de palabras con el fin de aclarar algo que ya se encuentra implícito y explícito en la oración.

En el contexto se ha utilizado la conjunción "que", es prescindible, pues enseguida se encuentra el adverbio interrogativo "quién", con éste último la duda ya está implícita: "pregunté quién estaba"
Ejemplo:
"Pensé que cómo estará el clima mañana"/ "Pensé en cómo estará el clima mañana"
"Le preguntaré que qué hará el sábado" "Le preguntaré qué hará el sábado"
Pero ejemplo:
"Me señaló que quienes vendrán a la fiesta estarán allá"
Ahí sí es necesario porque tiene el oficio de complemento circunstancial, (recalco que "quienes" es conjunción y no adverbio), Para estructurar recomiendo analizarlo así: ¿qué te señaló? que quienes vendrán estarán allá.

Yo recomiendo enfocarse en la construcción sintáctica de la oración completa para evitar estos errores, hay que tener cuidado en no omitir o reemplazar palabras que sí son necesarias pues también existe algo llamado "Elipsis" que es lo contrario al pleonasmo.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a nuestro sitio, Kudryavka. Tu aportación es interesante, pero debo hacer notar que, según el DLE, el _[queísmo](https://dle.rae.es/que%C3%ADsmo)_ es el uso de _que_ cuando se debería usar _de que_ (lo opuesto al dequeísmo). Eso no quita para que el resto de la respuesta sea acertada, efectivamente el uso de _que_ es prescindible en esa frase, pero fíjate que la propia RAE afirma que es un uso admitido. Te recomendamos buscar fuentes fiables para documentar tus respuestas (añadiendo enlaces) y que así te queden mucho mejor. ¡Esperamos más aportaciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: Es cierto que normalmente, la preposición omitida es "DE que" pero no es exclusiva, también sucede con otros nexos, un ejemplo EN: "- [...]quien insistió que un coche de un año […] [incorrecto].
- [...]quien insistió EN que un coche de un año [...]" El uso es admitido pero considerado así apartir de un "vulgarismo"